# Maximum length of the document libray file/folder sharepoint 2010?

Tags: document-library

From research i have came to conclusion that the maximum lenght of a folder/file name is 128 respectively, is it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The folder or filename itself can be 128 unicode characters. But there is a lot of factors to take into considerations as described in [URL path length restrictions (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the default document size threshold is set to 50MB, but can be changed to support the maximum boundary of 2GB.

You can refer this link : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Hope it helps...